# How to swap images on hover using Jquery and .fadeIn effect?

Tags: jquery, image, replace, hover, swap

Title says it all. How do I swap my image on hover using JQuery and the .fadeIn effect?

I have a  tag with a B&W image inside of it. When you hover over the link I want the B&W image to be swapped with a color version and fade in. I'm looking for a similar effect as the photos at this website:

http://www.manuelle-gautrand.com/

My naming convention for my B&W images end with _bw while my color images are the same name without the _bw.

Here's my HTML:

```
<a href="link.html" class="item"><img src="images/cool_restaurant_bw.jpg" alt="Cool Restaurant" width="200" height="300"></a>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".item").hover( function() {
        $(this).find("img").stop().fadeOut(0, function() {
            $(this).find("img").attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("_bw", ""));}).fadeIn(400);
    },
        $(this).find("img").stop().fadeOut(0, function() {
            $(this).find("img").attr("src", $(this).attr("src") + "_bw");}).fadeIn(0);
    );
});
```

My code isn't working. Any advice?

Thanks all in advance

Comment: In here :------> `$(this).attr("src").replace("_bw",)`, replace `"_bw"` with what? You are missing one parameter.

Comment: You need to change that to `$(this).attr("src").replace("_bw", "")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you use an image preloader you will run into problems with loading when changing the `src`.

Better to load all images (note the `display:none;` on the top image).

Then use the jQuery `toggle()` and `fadeIn() fadeOut()` functions.
If you don't want the white flash at the start of hover (which is the same as the link you posted) then you can remove the `toggle()` statements.

```js
$(".item").hover(
  function() {
    // fade in
    $(this).find('.bottom-image').toggle(0);
    $(this).find('.top-image').fadeIn(500);
  }, function() {
    //fade out
    $(this).find('.bottom-image').toggle(0);
    $(this).find('.top-image').fadeOut(500);
  }
);
```

```css
.bottom-image,
.top-image {
  position: absolute;
}

.bottom-image {
  background-color: #777;
}
.top-image {
  display: none;
  background-color: #33a;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a href="link.html" class="item">
  <img src="images/cool_restaurant_bw.jpg" alt="Cool Restaurant" width="200" height="300" class="bottom-image">
  <img src="images/cool_restaurant.jpg" alt="Cool Restaurant" width="200" height="300" class="top-image">
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Tims. This is perfect. I didn't think I would be able to accomplish this with two images using position:absolute but I found a way to make it work. This is perfect. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I would do one thing a little differently, and that is to make the color-image the background image of the link instead of exchanging the sources. If you exchange the sources it won't be able to fade from one image into the other - for that to be possible, they both have to be there at the same time.

Instead, I would add a little function that goes through all your images and sets the color-images as background images:

```
$('.item').each(
    function() {
        var colorbg = $(this).find('img').attr('src').replace("_bw", "");
        $(this).css('background', 'url(' + colorbg + ')');
    }
);
```

You'll also have to add some CSS to the link:

```
.item {
    display: block;
    height: 300px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Then you can just animate the image to fade in and out the way you want on hover:

```
$('.item').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, 0);
        $(this).find('img').stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, 0);
        $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, 500);
    },
    function() {
        $(this).find('img').stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, 0);
    }
);
```

(The function above makes first both the link and the image "invisible", then fades in the link i.e. the color-image.)

Here's a fiddle (using different picture sources): http://jsfiddle.net/Niffler/Lvpx9h3j/

Comment: I appreciate the answer Niffler. I'm looking for an overall effect where the original image disappears then the new image quickly appears in the same place. I edited the OG post with a link to the effect I'm trying to replicate.

Comment: @NicholasSmith I've updated the script to have the same effect as the link you posted. Would you mind checking the fiddle to see whether that is how you meant it?